# Best way to model pricelist per customer for products in webshop

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-development, postgres

I am making a b2b-webshop system that will have multiple customers. Each customer will have a separate active pricelist which contains the products that they can buy and the prices that applies for that customer.

I am struggling designing this. What is a good practice?

My database looks like below right now, and Im thinking about adding a Pricelist-table that contains which products are active, price and a customerId and then queyring this to get products to display for each customer. But it seems a little backwards?

Use case 1:

Admin adds a new product. The product will be on display for customer with ID 4.
Admin goes to the pricelist admin-page and adds the new product to customer 4's pricelist which contains 0-X products. Admin sets the price that this customer will have for that product and clicks save.

Use case 2:

A customer goes in to the order page. A list of products are shown based on the items in a pricelist set up for this customer(ID 4).

[image]

Comment: Could you add one or two Use Cases with which the persons that use your system, will interact with that application as a whole? Maybe this can give us some insights on the workings of the database.

Comment: @kiltek Sure! Updating question now

Comment: @kiltek Updated, please see question again!

Answer (score -1):

Having read your now-edited question...

I think you need a Customer-Product link table on which the price lives.
CustomerProduct has a customer id, product id, and compulsory price field (maybe even currency depending on your customer base?)